# Error running '__rvm_make install' when installing openssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, openssl, installation

I'm trying to set up Ruby on Rails on a Ubuntu server.  I don't care which version of ruby as long as I find one that works, but I'm working with v2.1.0.  Whenever I try to run any `sudo gem ...` commands I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I've figured that I just have to install openssl, but when I try it using `rvm pkg install openssl` it works for a while but then fails and gives the following output:

```
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
Fetching openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz to /home/ubuntu/.rvm/archives
Extracting openssl to /home/ubuntu/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1g...
Configuring openssl in /home/ubuntu/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1g..................................
Compiling openssl in /home/ubuntu/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1g.............................................................................................................................
Installing openssl to /home/ubuntu/.rvm/usr.............................
Error running '__rvm_make install',
showing last 15 lines of /home/ubuntu/.rvm/log/1401942843/openssl_make.install.log
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1g/tools'
installing man1/CA.pl.1
installing man1/asn1parse.1
installing man1/ca.1
installing man1/ciphers.1
installing man1/cms.1
cms.pod around line 457: Expected text after =item, not a number
cms.pod around line 461: Expected text after =item, not a number
cms.pod around line 465: Expected text after =item, not a number
cms.pod around line 470: Expected text after =item, not a number
cms.pod around line 474: Expected text after =item, not a number
POD document had syntax errors at /usr/bin/pod2man line 71.
make: *** [install_docs] Error 255
+ return 2

Please note that it's required to reinstall all rubies:

    rvm reinstall all --force

Updating openssl certificates..
```

I have a few openssl directories all ready on my system and I've tried reinstalling ruby several times using parameters like `--use-openssl-dir` pointing to each one but I still get the exact same error shown at the top of this post.  I'm sure that I have to somehow get `rvm pkg install openssl` to work.  Any insight would be appreciated.

*UPDATE* Well I just nuked my version of ruby and installed it again fresh and it is working fine now.